# DPA Recording Techniques

Tags: dpa, recordings

So Ive bought a pair of DPA 4061s. One of my main reason for getting these was discreet field recording. I’ve heard about people putting them in hats, or on ear phone holders allowing them to do discreet and good quality recordings around town without flashing big shotgun mics around.

So re- Binaural recording, say using them in earpieces. I’m not so interested in the binaural technique as seems to be more for headphone playback. But if I record binaurally for logistical/convenience reasons, are these stereo recordings going to work effectively in a film playback? Ie - using them to tracklay for features. 
Any help/suggestions/technieques for recording with these would be much appreciated?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They should work, but do remember that just like ORTF, the stereo image is partially the result of  time delays in reaching each mic diaphragm (the two parts of a stereo image being a sound source's projected amplitude and resulting time delay between reaching capsules).  With XY and MS, there is no time delay playing into the stereo image result.  When time delays exist, phasing will be an issue to watch for.  You'll probably have to experiment to see how it works, and you get lucky and not have any issues.  But on a theoretical level - phase coherence is something you'll want to keep on your radar whenever the capsules are not existing within the same 'point' in space.

Comment: Thanks, thats very useful information. I figured it would be a case of experimenting, but especially as I tracklay in 5.1, I will keep a close eye on phase.

Comment: The phase issues are mostly with regard to collapsing to a lower-channel denomination (like stereo to mono) and phase-matrices like LtRt and LstRst

Comment: Yeh of course, thats whats I meant,  as in mainly issues with LtRT, as rarely asked to make mono stems these days. Thanks again

Comment: Nitpick: Time delays exist everywhere in the physical world :) It's just that some of the microphone techniques sound more natural to us than the others or their placement rejects some of the frequencies or direct sound that would cause comb filtering, which explains why there are guidelines for angles and capsule distance and why the techniques work so well.

Comment: If two capsules occupy the same space, the time arrival of a singular sound source to both capsules will be identical from a horizontal plane.  Hence, both capsule's capture of the sound source will be phase coherent.

Comment: The time delay from the sound source will be identical for both capsules, resulting in no time delay BETWEEN both capsules' capturing of said sound source.

Comment: Problem is, 4061s are omnidirectional. So attempting to make an XY recording with this rig would be a less than ideal use of your recording time and hard drive space.

Comment: True.  I think what I said is simply being lost in translation.  I use Xy only as an example where two capsules occupy the same space, therefor no phase to worry about because the sound source arrives at the capules at the aame time.

Comment: Yeah, I recognize that you're not recommending XY/MS in your answer. I just thought the comments got off on a nitpick tanget and, while true, it's not necessarily relevant to the original question.